# Run solana-test-validator shows initializing but does not work

Tags: solana

macOS 11.6.3

solana-cli 1.9.6 (src:781609b2; feat:2191737503)

```
Config File: /Users/sumbuk/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: http://localhost:8899 
WebSocket URL: ws://localhost:8900/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /Users/sumbuk/.config/solana/id.json 
Commitment: confirmed
```

After running `solana-test-validator`, the message showed 'initializing...' briefly but after that nothing happened. Can anyone kindly point me in a direction? Thanks.

```
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about anything else that you're seeing?  Also, as a first attempt, could you run `solana-test-validator -r` to reset the ledger?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I wasn't able to run `solana-test-validator -r` at the time. I finally solved it by reinstalling solana-cli a couple of times and following up on the instruction of example-helloworld on solana-lab. Still have no idea what the problem was.

Comment: Great to hear that it all worked out in the end!